# Entity Framework lost the value of my field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, mapping

I use Entity Framework for my MVC project.
I have this model that have specific field that after i query it will have a value. By the time I use MapToModel the value of that specific field lost and will turn to null. Can anyone explain to me what happened?

Example:
this is the source model

```
 public partial class DRAWING_PROCESS : Entity
{
    public decimal DRAWING_PROCESS_ID { get; set; }
    ....
    public string field_that_lost_its_field { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the view model

```
 public partial class DRAWING_PROCESS_VIEWMODEL
{
    public decimal DRAWING_PROCESS_ID { get; set; }
    ....
    public string field_that_lost_its_field { get; set; }
}
```

after the query `field_that_lost_its_field` from the model will have a value of "CdBlg", but after i map it to the view model using the MapToModel the value of the field `field_that_lost_its_field` on the viewmodel was null and not "CdBlg"

Comment: How are you using these in the view?

Comment: How do you map your `Entity` to `ViewModel`?

Comment: You'll need to post a minimal reproducible example including how you are populating your view model.

Comment: Are you using some sort of automapper, is the type and name of the property exactly the same and they both have public getters and setters etc? Just post the exact code you are using, there is nothing "secrety" enough to hide about a named property. Also you are talking about a 'field' instead of a property, is it actually a Field or a Property?

Comment: @GurpreetKailey yes